# WP - Gravity Forms / User registration - Mapping Multiselect & Checkbox

Tags: wordpress, registration, gravity-forms-plugin, gravity, gravityforms

I've created a Gravity form with the User register addon.

Into this form, I want to propose a checkbox with multiple choices.
This checkbox is associated with "Marque" field.
"Marque" is an information I want to get back on my users profile.

[image: Checkbox associated with "Marque" field into the Feed Settings form]

[image: Checkbox completion on the registration form]

When I complete the registration form with some check, I am not able to retrieve the checks value into the user profil...

[image: Checkbox values into the custom field]

[image: Empty box into the user profile]

Is it a mapping issue between the value I can get on my registration form and the value I can get due to my custom fields ?

Same issue is happened with "Multiselect" field into my registration form.

If yes, how can I fix it ?

Thanks,
FX

Comment: Please add your code, otherwise it is difficult to tell where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my Gravity field mapping issue !

https://gist.github.com/spivurno/35e169a197dee221cca5473d1d642cf3